# Setting Z-index for a absolute position nested inside of a fixed container

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have a header tag that I set a fixed property to. Inside that header tag, I have a nav tag that I set to be absolute positioned. The issue I am having is I can't seem to pull the header tag to sit in front of the nav tag. Even with setting the header tag to a z-index of 1000 and the nav tag to a z-index of 500. Is what I am trying to do possible?

```
<header> <-- fixed position
   <section> logo here </section>
   <nav data-nav="main-navigation">   <-- absolute position
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#" id="selected">HOME <div></div></a></li>
         <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">GALLERIES</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
  </header>
```

Here is a code pen to show what I am trying to do

[CSS position codepen](https://codepen.io/icekomo/pen/YjaEwB)

Comment: If I set the nav to have a -1 z-index, the background-color for the header tag doesn't show.

Comment: you made a typo `:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `position: fixed`, the child element can't sit behind its parent. The trick is to use a pseudo-element on the parent, which will act as a sibling to the child.

With what you've described, the text will be behind the header color.

```css
header{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

header::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}

header nav{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  top:0;
}

header ul{
  list-style:none;
}

header a{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HELLO</h1>
  
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

If you want the text to show up on top of the red, you would need to use a pseudo-element on `nav` instead. If you don't need `position: fixed`, you can use any other positioning on the parent combined with a negative `z-index` on the child:

```css
header{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

header nav{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  top:0;
  z-index: -1;
}

header ul{
  list-style:none;
}

header a{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HELLO</h1>
  
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: So is it possible to have the header fixed, use the pseudo-element class and still have the content of the header show?

Comment: If you can create an image of what you are trying to accomplish, I could provide a more concrete example of code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly what you want, but check this

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxmPNg)

Basically I changed the `position`and changed some HTML.

Hope it helps!